Add content warning to automated Bluesky post in TypeScript?
I'm trying to make a bot for Bluesky that posts content that can be NSFW, and I need to use Bluesky's "Content Warning" feature to mark such posts as containing Adult Content, as you can through the webpage or app.
I've tried looking through the documentation for creating a post, but nowhere in there does it describe how one is supposed to add a content warning to the media being uploaded.
